# react native wheel picker (IOS) is not stay on selected value?

Tags: react-native, timepicker, picker

> this works absolutely fine on android but not on IOS (not displaying value which user select from wheel picker). Check this Link.
>
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y_ULGQuvPlzZj2V2zr1RAynrZKpme4Uc/view?usp=sharing

```
 <Picker
          style={{ width: 100, height: 80 }}
          selectedValue={this.state.selectedHour}
          itemStyle={{ color: "black", fontSize: 20 }}
          onValueChange={index => this.onPickerHourSelect(index)}
        >
          {this.state.hourList.map((value, i) => (
            <PickerItem label={value} value={i} key={"money" + value} />
          ))}
```

```
onPickerHourSelect(index) {
 var hour = this.state.hourList[index];

this.setState({
  selectedHour: hour,
})   }
```

> Please suggest me another component or package of picker(Like Spinner Or Wheel Picker)

Comment: Are you using react-native-picker?

Comment: I'm using react-native-wheel-picker

Comment: try  react-native-picker

Comment: Still its not working.

Comment: Can you please share your code which you tried into react-native-picker?

Comment: Have you solved error or not?

Comment: now, I'm using DatePickerIOS component

Comment: is it working or not?

Comment: Picker component is not worked for me but only for "IOS" platofrm. so now I'm using DatePickerIOS component ( for IOS ).

Comment: what about android?

Comment: for android I've use react-native-wheel-picker  and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem! I solved it using selectedValue instead of selectedItem and passing the pickerItem's value.

This is my code:

```html
<Picker style={{flex: 1, width: 150, height: 180}}
        itemStyle={{color: 'black', fontSize: 26}}
        selectedValue={this.state.minutes[this.state.indexSelected]}
        onValueChange={(index) => {this.setState({indexSelected: index})}}>
        {this.state.minutes.map((value, i) => (<PickerItem label={value} value={i} key={i}/>))}             
</Picker>
```

Comment: thank you so much roberto. but I've also use selectedValue. see my code snippet.